# Swiftmailer still sends email despite disable_delivery or delivery_address

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I have setup a staging environment (uat). The intent is to redirect all emails to one single email address or worst case disable email functionality.
My issue is that despite the following setup, the application is still sending email as it should in prod environment.

```
# config_uat.yml
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }

monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler:      nested
        nested:
            type:  stream
            path:  "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug

swiftmailer:
    transport:      smtp
    host:           127.0.0.1
    port:           25
    encryption:     null
    sender_address: info@gpsc.cwtwebpem.com
    logging:        "%kernel.debug%"
    delivery_address: 'bastien@vial-collet.fr'
    disable_delivery: true
```

And :

```
#config.yml
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: "@psmdbBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }
    - { resource: "@psmdbBundle/Resources/config/version.yml" }

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport:      smtp
    host:           127.0.0.1
    port:           25
    encryption:     null
    sender_address: info@domain.com
    logging:        "%kernel.debug%"
```

[EDIT]

I have setup a app_uat.php. It is based on app.php:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ApcClassLoader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';

// Use APC for autoloading to improve performance.
// Change 'sf2' to a unique prefix in order to prevent cache key conflicts
// with other applications also using APC.
/*
$loader = new ApcClassLoader('sf2', $loader);
$loader->register(true);
*/

//require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';
//require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppCache.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('uat', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
//$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

[EDIT 2]
I have checked and the prod environment is running instead of uat.
I can't manage to setup my apache config to run uat... Here it is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName uat.gpsc.domain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/uat.gpsc.domain.com/current/web
    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/uat.gpsc.domain.com/current/web>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Allow from All

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_uat.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>

    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/uat.project_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/uat.project_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you accessing the site through **app_uat.php**? (a new front controller file in the web directory, you should have created) And in that file, you should have set:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('uat', true);//or 'uat', false
```

This is the process described at http://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/environments.html

Please update your answer with your app_uat.php if you did create one.

---

EDIT: **This is a problem with the way you've set up Apache**, since your app_uat file seems correct. But I'll leave the previous part of my answer, in case anyone else needs it (it's a good first step).

**From looking at your apache configuration file, everything seems fine**. But please also make sure:

1. Remove the line `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` and its closing tag... So you're forced to have the rewrite module on! `sudo a2enmod rewrite` to activate Apache's rewrite module.
2. Make sure to restart apache `sudo service apache2 restart`
3. `AllowOverride All` means any htaccess files can override the behavior. Make sure this isn't happening. List any hidden files in the symfony root folder, or its web folder by doing `ls -a`

Comment: Yes I have a app_uat.php and I am accessing the application through this front controller.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question. Your problem is definitely in Apache. I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: As you suggested the issue was related to AllowOverride All and a the default .htaccess provided by Symfony framework.